# How to define AWS IAM attribute-based access control in terraform

Tags: json, variables, terraform, amazon-iam

I am defining attribute-based access control (ABAC) for AWS IAM within my terraform file. Sample policy is

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "testS3" {
name = "testS3"

policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-${aws:PrincipalTag/team}*"
    }
]
}
EOF
}
```

How do I call that **${block}** within terraform? Terraform translates that into its own variables.

Comment: That does not look like proper terraform syntax... Are you trying to escape the `${aws:PrincipalTag/team}` on that string?

Comment: Yes, I figured I need to add extra `$` to make it work. It worked with `$${aws:PrincipalTag/team}`

Comment: It might worth linking to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html in your question to avoid confusing Terraform folks who may not be aware that IAM Variables use the same syntax as Terraform String Template interpolations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked with extra `$` in the string.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "testS3" {
name = "testS3"

policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-$${aws:PrincipalTag/team}*"
   }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

I also tried with `variables.tf` file and referenced the variable here in json.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "principaltag" {
default = "$${aws:PrincipalTag/tedteam}"
}

****
```

**policy.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "testS3" {
name = "testS3"

policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-${var.principaltag}*"
   }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```